# How to remove downloaded videos of TED app from device?

Tags: video, storage

I like official [TED](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ted.android) app which allows me to download videos for later offline viewing. I've downloaded many videos & watched all of them. Now, I want to remove them from my device to regain my storage space. But, I am unable to find option in app for this. I've looked in file system, but unable to find downloaded videos. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `My Talks` tab, tap/press options button (you can tap the overflow menu in the top right corner if you are on tablet).

There is a `Remove Items` in menu. That should do the trick. It puts an `x` on all the videos and I'm assuming a tap on that will delete them.  I haven't done this, because I haven't gotten around  to watching them yet.

Comment: There's no overflow menu in the top right corner. Instead, there's a listen button. Anyway, thanks.. the later objectives are same.

Comment: Sorry, I was on a tablet.  Tapping the menu button does the exact same thing.

Comment: Merge my answer in your own, so that I could delete my answer & accept yours..

Comment: I've done this.. waiting until its peer reviewed..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Done.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.
While on `My Talks` tab, press/tap *options* button to bring menu. From this menu, tap `Remove Items` which would allow you to selectively remove downloaded videos.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can remove the TED videos in bulk:

1. Go to the path `/sdcard/Android/data/com.ted.android/files/` using your file manager in Android. Delete all the videos directly from there.
2. In your TED app, go to `My Talks` menu and then tap the vertical dotted icon at the right-top corner which will popup a dropdown menu. You should tap the `Remove Items` option which will show `x` at the left of each of the downloaded videos that you want to remove.

Hope it helps.